# Как добавить разделение по тысячам в числах?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно из "12345" сделать "12 345", то есть, привести числа в нормальный вид. Насколько я понял, этим занимается `NumberFormat`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К ответу выше можно добавить более точную реализацию NumberFormat:

```
int num = 12345;
String str = NumberFormat
    .getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
    .format(num)
    .replace(",", " ");
```

> 12 345

Answer (score 2):

## String.format()

```
int num = 12345;
String str = String.format("% d", num);
```

> 12 345

## NumberFormat

```
int num = 12345;
String str = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(num));
```

> 12,345

## DecimalFormat

```
int num = 12345;
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("# ###");
String str = myFormatter.format(num);
```

> 12 345